# Producing probability of wins in Python craps game

Tags: python

I have the logic down for this game of craps. My only problem right now is that I can't seem to get any output for finding the probability of wins for the game. Here is the code:

```
from random import seed, randint



def simulate():
  die1 = randint(1, 6)
  die2 = randint(1, 6)
  roll = die1 + die2

  first_roll = roll

  if first_roll == 7 or first_roll == 11:
    return True
  elif first_roll == 2 or first_roll == 3 or first_roll == 12:
    return False
  else:
    second_roll = randint(1, 6) + randint(1, 6)
    while second_roll != first_roll and second_roll != 7:
      if second_roll == first_roll:
        return True
      elif second_roll == 7:
        return False
        


  

## Main


def probability(n):
  simulate()
  wins = 0
  for i in range(n):
    if simulate() == 1:
      wins += 1
  return 

print(probability(10000))
```

I want to find the probability of wins for 10000 trials. However, I don't get any output when running this code. Nothing shows up. Where am I going wrong on this? I have tried for a couple hours but nothing seems to be working for me. Please include code and what I was doing wrong. I know for a fact that it should be 49% but I can't seem to arrive at that answer.

Comment: You are mistaken if you think you have the logic down. Your `simulate()` sometimes returns `None` and sometimes hangs in an infinite loop. Debug that before you try to estimate any probabilities.

Comment: You need to calculate `second_roll` again for each time there's not a win or loss. You're returning `True` or `False` but testing for a numeric value. Your `probability` function doesn't return the number of wins. You also need at least one more `else` and one more `return` in your `simulate` function.

Comment: In your `else` clause you return nothing if execution doesn't enter the `while` loop and you get stuck in that loop forever if you do enter the loop. A while loop in which nothing ever happens to change the condition of the loop is an infinite loop. It is that `else` that you really need to debug.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have since changed the else function and debugged it. I have created another function before simulate() in which it rolls two dice and returns the sum. In doing that, I have also changed the else statement to say, new_dice (instead of second_roll) to call the roll() function (newly created function). Moving on, my else statement now says new_dice = roll(), while True: .... , if new_dice == first_roll() , then return True. If the new_dice == 7, then return False.

Comment: I have also edited the probability function. It now says, probability(n), wins = 0, for i in range(n): if simulate() == 1: wins += 1. I also added a return statement to return the amount of wins divided by n. Finally, I printed out the result, which gave me about 49%

Comment: @roTenshi2 Sounds like you solved your problem. Congratulations.

Comment: While it is true that in `if simulate() == 1:`, `True` is equal to `1`, it is more readable to simply use `if simulate():`. Otherwise, why not just do `wins += simulate()` without the `if` (I'm not recommending that)?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for my latest answer, I didn't read that its craps game.

```py
from random import seed, randint

def simulate():
    die1 = randint(1, 6)
    die2 = randint(1, 6)
    roll = die1 + die2

    first_roll = roll

    if first_roll == 7 or first_roll == 11:
        return True
    elif first_roll == 2 or first_roll == 3 or first_roll == 12:
        return False
    else:
        while True:
            second_roll = randint(1, 6) + randint(1, 6)

            if second_roll == first_roll:
                return True
            elif second_roll == 7:
                return False
                


# Main
def probability(n):
    wins = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if simulate() == 1:
            wins += 1
    return wins


print(probability(100000))
```

I think its the answer, I changed the second part of `simulate()`
where its returning `True`, when `second_roll == first_roll`, returning `False` when `second_roll==7`, and repeats that `while` loop by continue, if second_roll is equal to other number.

Comment: No, you need two die. [Craps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps) uses two. And the [probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps#Bet_odds_and_summary) (second and third tables in that section) in craps are not equal for each total.

Comment: Your first change snippet is wrong. Please read the rules of craps.

Comment: Your `else:`/`continue` is superfluous.

Comment: Okey, I think now it's done correctly @DennisWilliamson